# Dropdown JavaScript onClick event not firing in Chrome/IE

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

This doesn't work in chrome and IE. I'm not so good at Javascripting so I don't know what to look for. So what can I do to make this work? I have searched here to find some solution, but no luck.

Javascript code:

```
function show(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.style.display = "";
}

function hide(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.style.display  = "none";
}

function hideAll() {
    hide('child1');
    hide('child2');
    hide('child3');
    hide('child4');
    hide('child5');
}
```

HTML code

```
    <select name="parent" id="parent">
<option value="0" selected>Please choose</option>
<option value="1" onclick="hideAll(); show('child1');">Parent 1</option>
<option value="2" onclick="hideAll(); show('child2');">Parent 2</option>
<option value="3" onclick="hideAll(); show('child3');">Parent 3</option>
<option value="4" onclick="hideAll(); show('child4');">Parent 4</option>
<option value="5" onclick="hideAll(); show('child5');">Parent 5</option>
</select>
</p>
<select name="child1" id="child1" style="display:none">
<option value="1">Child1 - 1</option>
<option value="2">Child1 - 2</option>
<option value="3">Child1 - 3</option>
<option value="4">Child1 - 4</option>
<option value="5">Child1 - 5</option>
</select>
<select name="child2" id="child2" style="display:none">
<option value="1">Child2 - 1</option>
<option value="2">Child2 - 2</option>
<option value="3">Child2 - 3</option>
<option value="4">Child2 - 4</option>
<option value="5">Child2 - 5</option>
</select>
<select name="child3" id="child3" style="display:none">
<option value="1">Child3 - 1</option>
<option value="2">Child3 - 2</option>
<option value="3">Child3 - 3</option>
<option value="4">Child3 - 4</option>
<option value="5">Child3 - 5</option>
</select>
<select name="child4" id="child4" style="display:none">
<option value="1">Child4 - 1</option>
<option value="2">Child4 - 2</option>
<option value="3">Child4 - 3</option>
<option value="4">Child4 - 4</option>
<option value="5">Child4 - 5</option>
</select>
<select name="child5" id="child5" style="display:none">
<option value="1">Child5 - 1</option>
<option value="2">Child5 - 2</option>
<option value="3">Child5 - 3</option>
<option value="4">Child5 - 4</option>
<option value="5">Child5 - 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".

Comment: What is the expected behavior. Does it behave as you'd expect it to in any browser.

Comment: JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/B5Zvk/

Comment: when i select parent 1, child1 dosnt popup. But it does in opera..

Comment: You might want to consider using some javascript framework like jQuery to perform such tasks

Comment: yes, but i dont know how to make it. Like i said, im very new to javascripting. And i dont know what to search for to find a script like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use onchange instead of onclick

Here is a complete solution which does not care what the IDS are as long as the values of the parent select match the IDs of the selects to hide and show

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/pg6Lp)

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("disc").onchange=function() {
    hideAll(this); 
    var id = this.value;
    if (id) show(id);
  }
}

function show(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    if (el) el.style.display = "block";
    else alert("No such ID as "+id);
}

function hide(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.style.display  = "none";
}

function hideAll(sel) {
  var allSels=document.getElementsByTagName("select");
  for (var i=0;i<allSels.length;i++) {
      if (allSels[i]!=sel) {
          console.log(allSels[i].id)
          allSels[i].style.display='none';
      }    
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice. But if i want to change to "Discraft" how can i hide the second <select>?  I dont want to write down every <select> when im gonna take it out from an database.

Comment: So be more clear in your specs. Use document.getElementsByTagName("select") and hide all except the parent using a loop

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r95xF/8/ like that, but when i select DX it has to popup under?

Comment: is there a way to past the idx to an php string?

Comment: Sure. Ajax or submit the form

Comment: yes i tried to submit the form of each select, but when i select te first form, im back to start, the second dont show up.

Comment: Ok Enough here. Please Open a new question if you have new issues

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <select name="parent" id="parent" onChange="showHide(this.id)">

      function showHide(id)
     {
        hideAll();
       var elementId = document.getElementById(id).value ;
       document.getElementById("child"+elementId).style.display= "block";

     }
```

Comment: here selected value come as 1,2,3,4.Then the block we are showing is  "child1,child2.......Before that we are hiding all the elements

Comment: That worked. But if i what to select one i the child, and than another child pops up, how can i do that?

Comment: How can i hide the first selected if i change the parent?

Comment: this.id is not what you want to pass. Pass this and use its value